# get the data-id attribute of the destination element ondrop event

Tags: javascript, angular

So obviously the event object is pretty big and hard to navigate. I am trying to get the data-id attribute of my target element using the ondrop event. so

```
onItemDrop(event: any) {
    // Get the dropped data here
    console.log(event.///GET THE data-id attribute of the target element);
}
```

the html:

```
<div id="{{ column.id }}"
    class="board-body"
    data-id="{{ column.id }}"
    (onDrop)="onItemDrop($event)"
    droppable>
    <div class="card bg-light-blue mb-2" *ngFor="let item of (results | groupBy: column.id)" [dragData]="item" draggable>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-title mb-0">
                <h6>
                    <span class="text-primary"><strong>{{ item.contactName }}</strong></span>
                    <span class="text-secondary">- {{ item.mediaOutletName }}</span>
                </h6>
                <button class="btn btn-transparent p-0">
                    <small><i class="fa fa-caret-down p-0"></i></small>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="card-text text-dark">
                Sent: {{ item.updatedDate | date }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need this because I will then be adding to the script to change the data if the item dropped id so that it will matches the id of the element it was dropped into?

Comment: `event.target.dataset.id`?

Comment: @dfsq no that wasn't it

Comment: event.target.dataset.id should work